# Microsoft Visual Basic Active X error 429

Tags: excel, vba

I am running into an issue with ActiveX component can't create object error. The weird thing is the file was working perfectly fine until today. When the Ok button is pushed the form presents the user with the option to print form to PDF. I am getting an error on the Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application") Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

```
Dim fileOK As Boolean
Dim sPrinter As String

With Application
  sPrinter = .ActivePrinter
  fileOK = .Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
End With

If fileOK = True Then
   ChangeDefaultPrinter (Application.ActivePrinter)
   UserForm.PrintForm
   ChangeDefaultPrinter (sPrinter)
End If

Unload UserForm


End Sub


Public Sub ChangeDefaultPrinter(pName As String)

Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
oWord.WordBasic.FilePrintSetup Printer:=pName, DoNotSetAsSysDefault:=0
Set oWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: check your references.

Comment: Hi Doug, what should I look for in my references? This is strange to me bc I found out this form works for me but with the other users who access it on the share point they get the Active X error. Not sure what to look for as far as troubleshooting

Comment: Where do you "Dim" the object oWord, and what do you declare it as? Do you mean to leave the Word application running at the end of ChangeDefaultPrinter? It's possible people are running into problems because your code is leaving lots of orphaned Word applications running...

Comment: Hi Cindy. the code always worked until yesterday. How can I stop the orphaned Word applications from running? Also the code never had a Dim statement for the oWord object. I am no expert here so I am trying to figure this out as I am new to visual basic